# PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't work with hashes

Tags: php

Request Path: http://**localhost/1/2/# Example/**

```
print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Expected: **/1/2/# Example/**

Actual: /1/2/

Using `urldecode` doesn't have any effect because PHP is creating the array to begin with. Yes, this isn't an orthodox directory name though is there another way to determine the requested URI in PHP?

Comment: If this is an actual folder named `# Example` then you would need to urlencode the hash in the link to this page so the url becomes `/1/2/%23 Example/`. A URL hash (#whatever) is never sent over to PHP. It is available to the client side in javascript.

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5 „...the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
   processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
   from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
   identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
   solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.“ It's never sent to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # Parma is not send to the server!

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ah, right...I forgot about that...PHP ignores it. I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @John For the record, PHP doesn't "ignore it". It is removed by the browser and never even sent over to PHP.

Comment: You have over 24k reputation, how did you think that this was acceptable as an answer?

Comment: Actually it *was* good enough after I realized what he *intended* which I didn't at first because he is a native German speaker, not native English speaker.